# Extract embedded word doc from WordDocument (Apache POI 4.0.0)

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

I tried to extract the embedded word document in a word document.
I used the POIFSFileSystem to navigate the document, and I got that:

```
Try extract embedded files....
found entry: /SummaryInformation
found entry: /DocumentSummaryInformation
found entry: /ObjectPool
found entry: /ObjectPool/_1525700337
found entry: /ObjectPool/_1525700337/CompObj
found entry: /ObjectPool/_1525700337/ObjInfo
found entry: /ObjectPool/_1525700337/Package
found entry: /ObjectPool/_1546953926
found entry: /ObjectPool/_1546953926/ObjInfo
found entry: /ObjectPool/_1546953926/Ole10Native
found entry: /ObjectPool/_1546953926/CompObj
found entry: /ObjectPool/_1549950910
found entry: /ObjectPool/_1549950910/CompObj
found entry: /ObjectPool/_1549950910/ObjInfo
found entry: /ObjectPool/_1549950910/Package
found entry: /ObjectPool/_1570293946
found entry: /ObjectPool/_1570293946/CompObj
found entry: /ObjectPool/_1570293946/ObjInfo
found entry: /ObjectPool/_1570293946/Package
found entry: /ObjectPool/_1581762906
found entry: /ObjectPool/_1581762906/CompObj
found entry: /ObjectPool/_1581762906/ObjInfo
found entry: /ObjectPool/_1581762906/Package
```

But all of this embedded object is word document and one of them - TXT file.
Why all of them is Package?

Update.

I downloaded poi-bin-4.0.0-20180907.zip
But it dont containt org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.jar with XHTMLOptions class (I need it to convert docx to html).
Where I can find it jar?

Comment: Did you look at http://poi.apache.org/components/poifs/embeded.html ?

Comment: Yes! I look at "Files embedded in Word" on this page.

Comment: I do not understand why some files are packages, and some WordDocument files

Comment: You'd have to ask Microsoft about that....

Comment: @Gagravarr, I downloaded poi-bin-4.0.0-20180907.zip But it dont containt org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.jar with XHTMLOptions class (I need it to convert docx to html). Where I can find it jar? Or it class move to other package?

Comment: It should never have been there! An add-on was naughty and re-used the POI namespace... You want the project at https://github.com/opensagres/xdocreport/tree/master/thirdparties-extension/fr.opensagres.odfdom.converter.xhtml

Comment: Thanks, @Gagravarr!